# window.onbeforeunload not firing in Chrome but working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a main window and a pop up window. Popup window is created on the main window.

Like `parent.php` is the main window. On this page, I have a JavaScript function to reload the page as below:

```
function popUpClosed() {
  window.location.reload();
}
```

We can open popup window from parent.php. Now I want to execute `popUpClosed()` function on `parent.php` from popup window when we close / navigate the popup window.

I have tried following methods to achieve the same.

## Method 1

```
window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
    window.opener.popUpClosed();
  }
};
```

## Method 2

```
window.onbeforeunload = Call;

function Call() {
  if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
    window.opener.popUpClosed();
  }
}
```

## Method 3

```
window.onpagehide = function() {
  window.opener.popUpClosed();
}
```

Everything is working is fine in every browser except Google Chrome. Chrome is not firing any of the function.

**However, this is happening from last 2-3 days. Earlier all the things was working well in Chrome. (Might has been caused due to the latest Chrome updates)**

Any suggest will be appreciated.

Comment: Could very likely be a security fix. It is a very pornsite-like think to pop a window when the user wants to leave. An safer version is to use a mouseover on a div near the top of the window. Anthing in the console?

Comment: pagehide line is wrong

Comment: @mplungjan actually developer tools close when we close the window. so i am able to see the console. :D

Comment: @epascarello pagehide line is correct and working in firefox

Comment: @mplungjan in popup window, user to some data changes and then closes to see the updates done in the parent window.

Comment: @vitorio `window.addEventListener("pagehide", window.opener.popUpClosed());` is NOT correct. It is calling the method, not assigning the method.

Comment: Personally I would use postMessage()

Comment: @epascarello May be you are right but in my case it is working and i am able to execute the function on parent.php from my popup window. postMessage() is used to send message but i want to execute function. so if you have a solution please let me know by this method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127284/discussion-between-vitorio-and-epascarello).

Comment: The line `window.onpagehide=function(){ window.opener.popUpClosed(); }` is the one you see working I believe. The next line is invalid

Comment: @mplungjan The next line `window.addEventListener("pagehide", window.opener.popUpClosed());` is another method. Let me re-edit the question.

Comment: @mplungjan please read the edit again.

Comment: It is the same event but attached wrongly. The second parameter is supposed to be a function and you are executing one instead. `window.addEventListener("pagehide", function() { window.opener.popUpClosed() });` would work better

Comment: @mplungjan `window.addEventListener("pagehide", function() { window.opener.popUpClosed() });` not working in any browser. I think this is the wrong way to do so. But why above three methods not working in chrome but working in other browsers

Comment: Please. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener - assuming pagehide is triggered by the browser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917140/refresh-parent-page-on-close-of-pop-up-window

Comment: @Alex Methods are working but I want the above 3 methods to be working in chrome.

Comment: Might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726258/onbeforeunload-not-working-correctly-for-chrome

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can try the below code:

I have created the common function for open the POP up window:

```
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {
        var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
        var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

        width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
        height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

        var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
        var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;

        child = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

        if (child.focus) {
            child.focus();
        }
    }
```

For checking the child window closed or not I am using the `setInterval` function and check the interval like below:

```
function checkChild() {
    if (child != undefined && child.closed) {
            //alert("Child window closed");
            clearInterval(timer);
            location.reload();
        }
    }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/adminsunil/bejsxLyr/)

Comment: how can this get the bounty... It's a very bad idea to replace events with setInterval

Answer (score 1):

Latest google Chrome has a problem with `window.opener`. `window.opener` navigation inside a `beforeunload/unload` handler is ignored in the latest version. However there is a workaround for this. Try below code:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function detectClick(event) {
  var wind = window.open('urlhere', 'name', 'width=' + screen.width/2 + ', height=' + screen.height/2);
  wind.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
    popupClosed(wind);
  }
}
btn.addEventListener("click", detectClick, false);

function popupClosed(wind) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    wind.opener.location.href = window.location.href;
  }, 0);
}
```

```html
<input id= "btn" type="button" value="open popup" />
```

**THIS CODE WON'T EXECUTE HERE ON STACK OVERFLOW BUT WILL WORK IN BOTH: `Chrome` AND `Mozilla Firefox` WHEN EXECUTED THROUGH `jsfiddle` OR SERVER.**

Here is a working code: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aniketsahrawat/3Ldok1oy/5/)**

[here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660496) is the link of bug report that confirms `beforeunload/unload handler` issue.

Comment: Check [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660496) link @Kaiido

Comment: Ah my bad, actually this bug goes even through main window's function. But IMO a better workaround would be to place the timeout inside the `popupClosed()` function. Your answer makes it a bit unclear how you are solving OP's issue.

Comment: `popupClosed()` is using `window.location.reload()` and not something like `element.location.reload();`. There is no object of the `popup window` which makes it difficult to explain that is why i wrote the full code for this purpose. @Kaiido